# SQL - ORDER BY 'datetime' DESC

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have several values stored in my database as the `DATETIME` datatype (**YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**), and I've been trying to get them in a descending order - Greatest to least (In the case of dates - Newest to oldest), though, oddly enough, it seems to ignore the existence of the **DESC** operator entirely.

The SQL query (Abbreviated):

```
SELECT post_datetime FROM post WHERE type=`published` ORDER BY post_datetime DESC LIMIT 3
```

And from that, they print in this order:

```
2014-04-30 11:55:11
2014-07-01 12:25:40
2014-07-02 12:28:03
```

(Those happen to be the "oldest" date entries in the database too)

Solution? I'll note that using DESC on other things (Such as normal numbers) doesn't work either. I've checked my syntax, tried quotes, no quotes, double quotes & such.

(*Note* - I won't be able to answer any further questions for several hours, though I'll do my best to respond once I return)

---

***(6/11/17)***

**Edit**: To clarify, for future readers, the syntax typo was not related to the issue and was an error on my part when typing an example. I had been using a homemade query builder for so long that I had forgotten the proper syntax at the time. The issue lied within my program's logic—not the query. The above example has been edited and *is* correct solution for anyone looking to perform the mentioned task. I'm sorry this has been viewed over 50k times... but now you know.

Comment: That query should have been throwing at least one syntax error (given the use of `=` after `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`), and one error complaining that it couldn't find a column labeled `'post_datetime DESC'`.  You should have tried working through such errors first.

Answer (score 17):

1. use single quotes for strings
2. do NOT put single quotes around table names(use ` instead)
3. do NOT put single quotes around numbers (you can, but it's harder to read)
4. do NOT put `AND` between `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`
5. do NOT put `=` between `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` keywords and condition

So you query will look like:

```
SELECT post_datetime 
FROM post 
WHERE type = 'published' 
ORDER BY post_datetime DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT post_datetime 
FROM post 
WHERE type = 'published' 
ORDER BY post_datetime DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes here:

is:

```
ORDER BY = 'post_datetime DESC' AND LIMIT = '3'
```

Should be:

```
ORDER BY post_datetime DESC LIMIT 3
```